# onSenserChanged function not called in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sensors, accelerometer

I am making a application to measure the distance my android phone, but I don't know why my onSensorChanged function is not called while running.

```
Log.d("safik","sadfas;dfkasjf"); -> I added this line check if the function is called of not and I got that this function is not getting called.
```

I have used 3 sensors in this project(accelerometer, gravity and orientation).

the code was running fine but all of a sudden the project was not running, after some time I got to know that the onSensorChanged function was not getting called.

here is my code.

> ```
> package com.example.myapplication;
>
> import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
>
>
> import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.hardware.Sensor;
> import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
> import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
> import android.hardware.SensorManager;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.os.CountDownTimer;
> import android.os.SystemClock;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
>     private TextView textview;
>     private SensorManager sensorManager;
>     private double axx,ayy,azz,ax1,ay1,az1,ax2,ay2,az2,ax3,ay3,az3,ax4,ay4,az4,a;
>
>     private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
>     private double zThetaDegree,xThetaDegree,yThetaDegree,zTheta,xTheta,yTheta;
>     private double gravity;
>     private double distace = 0,u = 0,dt = 0,time1 = 0,converter = 1000000000,d = 0;
>     private boolean stage1,stage2,stage3,stage4,p,n;
>     private int repeat;
>
>     private Sensor sensorAcceleration,sensorOrientation,sensorGravity;
>
>
>     @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         textview = findViewById(R.id.textView);
>         sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
>         sensorAcceleration = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
>         sensorOrientation = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
>         sensorGravity = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
>
>
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
>         Log.d("safik","sadfas;dfkasjf"); 
>
>
>
>         if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY){
>             gravity = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[0],2)+Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1],2)+Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[2],2));
>
>             Log.d("gravity",Double.toString(gravity));
>         }
>
>         if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION){
>             zThetaDegree = (double) sensorEvent.values[0];
>             xThetaDegree = (double) sensorEvent.values[1];
>             yThetaDegree = (double) sensorEvent.values[2];
>
>             zTheta = (zThetaDegree * 3.1415)/180;
>             xTheta = (xThetaDegree * 3.1415)/180;
>             yTheta = (yThetaDegree * 3.1415)/180;
>
>             Log.d("theta",Double.toString(xTheta));
>         }
>
>         if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION){
>
>             dt =(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()) - time1;
>             dt = dt/(double) 1000000000;
>             time1 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
>
>             if(dt > 100000){
>                 dt = 0;
>             }
>
>
>             ax1 = (double) sensorEvent.values[3];
>             ay1 = (double) sensorEvent.values[4];
>             az1 = (double) sensorEvent.values[5];
>
>             //filtering rotation around y axis
>             az2 = (az1 * Math.cos(yTheta)) - (ax1 * Math.sin(yTheta));
>             ax2 = (az1 * Math.sin(yTheta)) + (ax1 * Math.cos(yTheta));
>             ay2 = ay1;
>
>             //filtering rotation around x axis
>
>             az3 = (az2 * Math.cos(xTheta)) - (ax2 * Math.sin(xTheta));
>             ax3 = ax2;
>             ay3 = (ay2 * Math.cos(xTheta)) + (az2 * Math.sin(xTheta));
>
>             //filtering rotation around z axis
>
>             az4 = az3;
>             ax4 = (ax3 * Math.cos(zTheta)) - (ay3 * Math.sin(zTheta));
>             ay4 = (ay3 * Math.cos(zTheta)) + (ax3 * Math.sin(zTheta));
>
>             //filtering gravity
>
>             az4 = az4 - gravity;
>             Log.d("az4", Double.toString(az4));
>
>
>
>             a = az4;
>
>
>             if(a == 0){
>                 stage1 = true;
>             }
>
>             if(stage1){
>                 if(a != 0){
>                     stage2 = true;
>                     stage1 = false;
>                     if(a > 0){
>                         p = true;
>                         n = false;
>                     }
>                     if(a < 0){
>                         n = true;
>                         p = false;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if(stage2){
>                 if(p){
>                     if(a < 0){
>                         stage3 = true;
>                         stage2 = false;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 if(n){
>                     if(a > 0){
>                         stage3 = true;
>                         stage2 = false;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if(stage3){
>                 if(a == 0){
>                     stage4 = true;
>                     stage3 = false;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if(stage4){
>                 u = 0;
>                 stage4 = false;
>             }
>
>             if(a < 0){
>                 if(-a < 0.09){
>                     a = 0;
>                 }
>             }
>             if(a > 0){
>                 if(a < 0.09){
>                     a = 0;
>                 }
>             }
>
>
>             if(a == 0){
>                 repeat = repeat + 1;
>                 if(repeat >= 10){
>                     u = 0;
>                     repeat = 0;
>                 }
>             }
>             else{
>                 repeat = 0;
>             }
>
>             u = u + a*dt;
>             distace = u*dt + ((a*dt*dt)/2);
>
>             d = d + distace;
>
>
>
>             textview.setText("distance is" + d + "   " + a);
>             Log.d("aaa", "d:" + Double.toString(d) + "   " + "distance:" + Double.toString(distace) + "   " + "    " + "u:" + Double.toString(u) + "     " + "a:" + Double.toString(a) + "    " + "dt:" + Double.toString(dt) + "    " + Double.toString(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()));
>         }
>
>
>     }
>
>
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onResume(){
>         super.onResume();
>         sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
>         sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
>         sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
>
>
>     }
>
>     protected void onPause(){
>         super.onPause();
>
>         sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
>     }
> }
> ```